# How to change the background color of a JToolTip using Nimbus LookAndFeel?

Tags: java, swing

In a Swing-based Java application using Nimbus LookAndFeel I try to set the background color of my tooltips. So I created a subclass of JToolTip and used it in my components by overriding createToolTip(). Fine so far and the tooltip is shown correctly, but the background color does not change. The foreground color is set as expected.
When changing the LookAndFeel to e.g. Metal I can set colors as expected.

Here a small example with ability to switch between Metal and Nimbus. As yopu hopefully see, the background color of the button's tooltip is only set when Metal is used.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToolTip;

public class TooltipTestApp {

private static final String METAL_LOOK_AND_FEEL = "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel";
private static final String NIMBUS_LOOK_AND_FEEL = "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel";
private static JButton button;
private static String usedLookAndFeel = NIMBUS_LOOK_AND_FEEL;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        button = new JButton() {

            @Override
            public JToolTip createToolTip() {
                JToolTip toolTip = super.createToolTip();
                toolTip.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                toolTip.setForeground(Color.RED);

                    return toolTip;
            }
        };

        button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                TooltipTestApp.toggleLookAndFeel();
            }
        });

        button.setToolTipText("Some text");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TooltipTestApp");

        TooltipTestApp.toggleLookAndFeel();
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setSize(450, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void toggleLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            if (usedLookAndFeel.equals(METAL_LOOK_AND_FEEL)) {
                usedLookAndFeel = NIMBUS_LOOK_AND_FEEL;
            } else {
                usedLookAndFeel = METAL_LOOK_AND_FEEL;
            }

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(usedLookAndFeel);

            String lookAndFeelName = usedLookAndFeel.substring(usedLookAndFeel.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            button.setText("This is: " + lookAndFeelName);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a hint: The used LookAndFeel is Nimbus. When changing this I am able to set the background color. So the question would be better "How to change the background color of a JToolTip when using Nimbus LookAndFeel?"

Comment: *"Any ideas?"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  For 'extra points' (or at least more help) make it so the GUI has a button to flip between Metal & Nimbus PLAFs.

Comment: @AndrewThomson: Thanks! I changed the example.

Comment: 3 comments.  1) An SSCCE should include the imports.  2) Re the exception `//should not happen here` a) Exceptions are for exceptional situations. b) A client running 1.6.0_09 would trigger that exception. c) `ex.printStackTrace()` is not only shorter than the comment, but far more useful.  3) I don't know how to solve the problem.  I cede to the Swing experts, who will hopefully happen by soon.

Comment: changed example: added imports and added exception handling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following also works for the Metal LAF without overriding the createToolTip() method:

```
UIManager.put("ToolTip.background", Color.RED);
```

LAF's can choose whether to use the UIManager properties or not. I have no idea if this will work with Nimbus.

Comment: @pmoule: Did you try a [derived color](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/nimbus/package-summary.html)?

Comment: @trashgod: I can't seen any effect and I'm not sure if I got it right. I tried `Color derivedColor = nimbusLaf.getDerivedColor("textForeground",1, 1, 1, 1, true);` and assigned this color by `toolTip.setBackground(derivedColor);`

Comment: For painting tooltips Nimbus uses an instance of the final type 'ToolTipPainter' with a hardcoded use of the Nimbus default value of 'info'. So I have 2 options. 1. globally change the default 'info' value with `UIManager.put("info", Color.BLACK);` 2. overriding the `UIDefaults` by setting an own Painter with `UIDefaults defaults = new UIDefaults(); defaults.put("ToolTip[Enabled].backgroundPainter", new MyTooltipPainter()); toolTip.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", defaults);`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 public class Main {
      public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JToolTip Sample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1") {
          public JToolTip createToolTip() {
            JToolTip tip = super.createToolTip();
            tip.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
            tip.setBackground(Color.RED);
            tip.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,36));
            return tip;
          }
        };
        b1.setToolTipText("HELLO");
        frame.add(b1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Source : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ModifythebehaviourofthedefaultJToolTip.htm

Comment: This code doesn't change the background color of the tooltip. You can add that with a simple `setBackground`, but that doesn't work in the Nimbus L&F.